# Alexa python lambda not able to import requests

Tags: python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on alexa in line code i have imported requests in my code but on run its giving error.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
from datetime import datetime
import requests
```

on testing Alexa on developer account its giving error as

**`"There was a problem with the requested skill's response"`**

getting this error only when i am adding the import requests

Comment: I am not familiar with Alexa, but I quite sure you can't import module with same name. You need `from botocore.vendored import requests as requests1` etc.

Comment: I want to use only import requests but on adding its giving error.

Comment: @LogitaKurrey are you still facing this issue. I could look more into it?

Comment: @NikhilWagh i have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

To use the package `requests` you need to upload this package along with your `lambda_function`, as it is not available with the virtual environment provided by lambda.

To do this, install `requests` package into the folder where your `lambda_function` is and then make a zip of the contents (not the folder but the contents) and then upload the zip file.

To install in your folder either do this :

1. `cd` to your folder and then `pip install requests`, or
2. `cd` to your folder and then `git clone git://github.com/requests/requests.git`

When you have installed the `requests` package contents of your folder should look something like [this](https://github.com/Nikhil-Wagh/Alexa-Flick).